# why Ajax json type keep showing 'undefined'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I tried to put db values into the html with Ajax..but it keeps showing 'undefined' letter in the place where db values supposed to be.

already checked there's no problem with the id values in html file..
and used alert(JSON.stringify(data)); to check if there's a problem with serving db value as well.

why the server page keep showing undefined?
can anybody help me to go through this...?

++ I used @Responsebody annotation for the Controller

```
const product_name_kor = document.getElementById('product_name_kor').innerText;
const product_name_eng = document.getElementById('product_name_eng').innerText;
const created_at = document.getElementById('created_at').innerText;
const released_price = document.getElementById('released_price').innerText;


$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/ReseltProject/shop/getProductInfo",
        data: {"product_name_kor":product_name_kor, 
               "product_name_eng":product_name_eng, 
               "created_at":created_at, 
               "product_id":product_id, 
               "released_price":released_price
               },
               
        success: function(data){
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            document.getElementById("product_name_kor").innerText = data.product_name_kor;
            document.getElementById("product_name_eng").innerText = data.product_name_eng;
            document.getElementById("created_at").innerText = data.created_at;
            document.getElementById("released_price").innerText = data.released_price;
            document.getElementById("product_id").innerText = data.product_id;
        },
        error: function(e){
          console.log(e);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: where is `dataType: "json"` ?

Comment: are you sure that `data` is of type object ? or just a json string ? try `console.log(data)` to check

Comment: @Responsebody  used at the Controller, so dataType is basically set to json

Comment: I think @ResponseBody only means that response will be auto serialize into json looking string, what matters is how jquery will comsume this response --- jquery will try to guess on how to process this using content-type is http response header, you should check on that or just use option `dataType: "json"` or enforce pre processing --- read more on "Data Types" in https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: please note that json string and json object is different thing